# how to post body containing Object instead of string to http api? angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post

I am using angular2 `http.post` in the following service:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

//Globals
const URL : string = 'http://myurl.com/listings';

@Injectable()
export class ListingsService {

  //Constructor
  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  postListing(data) {
   this.http.post(URL, data).map(res => res.json())
  }

}
```

The issue is that I am only allowed to post data as a string inside `http.post`, where as I need to pass in an Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this is using JSON.stringify for making a string of object and then JSON.parse on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to set Content-Type in your header. You can set default header as follows.

```
class MyOptions extends RequestOptions {
constructor() {
    super({
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    });
   }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   ...,
   provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as binariedMe mentioned, JSON.stringify will do what you want. 
If you want to send binary data maybe you want to look into BSON: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson